# Não consigo instalar pacote que criei .NET - NUGET

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

Recentemente criei um pacote no Nuget afim de realizar uns testes com um servidor Nuget privado.

Fiz da seguinte maneira no Visual Studio 2017:

- Criei um novo projeto Biblioteca de Classes (.NET Standard)
- Implementei o que eu precisava
- Em seguida, gerei o pacote

Fui até a pasta em que o pacote é gerado, peguei o arquivo .nupkg gerado e a pasta gerada e copiei para a pasta Packages do servidor Nuget.

Então ele gera uma pasta com o nome do pacote.

Após isso, abri uma aplicação MVC que usa o .NET Framework 4.6 e fui até ao gerenciador de pacotes para instalar o pacote que eu criei, e após a tentativa de instalação a seguinte mensagem foi exibida:

> "Não foi possível instalar o pacote 'Nome do Pacote'. Você está
>   tentando instalar este pacote em um projeto que se destina a
>   '.NETFramework, Version=4.6, mas o pacote não conte´m nenhuma
>   referência de assembly ou arquivo de conteúdo que seja compatível com
>   essa estrutura. Para obter mais informações, entre em contato com o
>   autor do pacote."

Como resolvo isso? Já procurei informações na documentação da Microsoft e não encontrei nada que pudesse me ajudar de maneira clara.

Comment: Você criou um pacote que não é compátivel com 4.6, precisa adequar esse pacote para que funcione nessa versão do .NET FRAMEWORK.! ? O problema pelo visto não é o pacote e sim a sua versão, em qual versão você fez o pacote?

Comment: O pacote foi feito na mesma versão.

Comment: Quem está contado isso é o próprio erro no momento da instalação, você não deve ter feito correto porque .NET Standard nem sempre é compativel (porque não foi feito isso) corretamente. Tem o arquivo do projeto?